# Android Volley JSON response

Tags: android, android-volley, json, postman

In my Android app I'm using [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) library.
I'm calling some service that returns json where one field called "order" and it's an int.

```
{
    ..... other fields .....
    "order" : 1
}
```

I called the same service with: 
1. `Postman (Chrome extension)`.
2. `Volley` through my code.

When I'm getting the response:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
```

The "order" field has different value between the 2 calls above.
* The service returns static data, so the difference cannot be there.
* All other field has the same values in those 2 calls.

**Is there any known bug with JSON field name "order" in `Volley` or `JSONObject` or any know issue?**

Comment: try it just for a test with "1" as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in Postman caching

It's better to disable the parameter "Auto save request" in the [settings](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/settings).